# Algorithm as an exercise

Tags: algorithm

So most everyone should know that `max_element(unsorted_array)` can be solved in `O(n)` time. I realized that while that it is easy to compute that, it seems it would be much harder to solve it in a less than optimal solution, such as `n*log(log(n))` time. Now obviously an algorithm could simply be `O(n + n*log(log(n)) )`, where the more time consuming part of the algorithm has no real purpose. At the same time, you could just use the regular `O(n)` algorithm `log(log(n))` times. Neither of these are very interesting.

So my question is, is there an algorithm that can find the max element in a set of numbers (stored in the container of your choice) in a way that there is no redundant loops or operations, but is Θ`(n*log(log(n)))` ?

Comment: Any particular reason you're thinking of `O(n*log(log(n))`? Or is that just something that spontaneously came into your head?

Comment: Probably the last panel of this: http://xkcd.com/342/

Comment: Any `f` in `O(n)` is also in `O(n * log(log(n))`.

Comment: edited question to make it more clear (although I can't figure how to put in a Greek symbol)

Comment: You can write big-Theta using &Theta;(n lg lg n).

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have it be more than \Theta(n), unless it's some strange data structure that is difficult to traverse (i.e. not \Theta(n).)

Comment: @Steve It's not meant to be a practical algorithm that I plan on using. I ask the question because I can't figure out any answer myself.

Comment: Fair enough. The usual solution is to just fill up the remaining time with noops, but that's not particularly interesting, as noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Van Emde Boas Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree)?

Comment: If the elements started in the tree it would be O(log(log(n)) time. Now if you had to insert them all into the tree first...this is a gray area!

Comment: How is this grey?  Inserting into the tree can't happen faster than O(n) and the premise is unsorted array.  Where is the grey?

Comment: Let me put this another way: If this is an acceptable answer then I suggest the answer: sorted array.  O(1) time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic misconception here:

**O(n + n*log(log(n)) ) is exactly identical to O(n log(log(n)))**

Please read the wiki page carefully:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

The Big-O notation is asymptotic.  This means that O(f(n) + g(n)) = O(max(f(n), g(n))) for all functions f, g.  This is not a trick, they are really equal.

Symbols like O(n^2), O(n), etc., are **not** functions, they are **sets**; specifically O(f(n)) means "the set of all functions which are asymptotically less than or equal to a constant times f(n)".  If f(n) >= g(n), then O(f(n)) contains O(g(n)) and so adding g(n) into that equation changes nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry, but as a math guys I have to nit-pick. Big-Oh (and the related notations) *are* functions. They simply take a function as input, and return a set of functions as there out put. So they really are higher-order functions. Still, it's a good answer

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde:  Hah!  You are technically correct!  But a specific Big O symbol when applied to something, like O(f(n)) for example, is actually a class of functions, which is what I was talking about in this context (and also in the context that the OP used them).  I edited the post to be a bit more clear.

Comment: And I guess if you want to be really technical, they are actually classes, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28set_theory%29, not sets.  Of course I didn't want to bring up that esoteric nonsense here and make things more confusing than they had to be.

Answer (score 0):

How about proof that it cannot be done.

Theory: It is possible to determine the maximum element of an unsorted array without examining every element.

- Assume you have examined all but one element of the unsorted array of n (n>1) items.
- There are two possibilities for largest element of the array.

  - The largest element you have yet seen (out of n-1).
  - The one element you have not seen

The unexamined element could be bigger (unless an examined element is the absolute maximum value representable); the array is unsorted.

Result: Contradiction.   You must examine the nth element in order to determine the maximum (in a mathematics context; you can take a shortcut in computer science under one probably rare circumstance)

Since it doesn't matter what value n has for this, it should apply for all n except the degenerate case (n=1)

If this isn't a valid response, I may be unclear on the requirements... ?

Comment: Isn't this disproving the idea that it can be done in log(log(n)) ?

Comment: My intent is to disprove that it can be done in better than O(n) time.  Since log(n) time is lower order (faster/better) than n, and since log(log(n)) is lower (faster/better) still, I think the answer to your question is: "Yes".